# HTML display result in text (input) field?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML form, with 3 input field, when you hit = button, it suppose to add 2 numbers that you typed in the first 2 input fields and display result in 3rd filed. Is it possible to do that? (I need result in a box (or table) or some thing rather than in plain text). I try the following but doesn't work (it does nothing), can somebody help me?

```
<HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sum</TITLE>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function sum()
          {
             var num1 = document.myform.number1.value;
             var num2 = document.myform.number2.value;
             var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
             document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = sum;
          }
        </script>
      </HEAD>

      <BODY>
        <FORM NAME="myform">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number1" VALUE=""> + 
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number2" VALUE="">
          <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE="">
        </FORM>

      </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Set the *value* attribute of the input field to equal the sum.

Comment: ` <input type = "text" value = "abc"   id="text"/>`
  
` <input type = "button" value ="pressme" onclick= "alert('getElementById("text").value')" >` This is not working can you help me ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`innerHTML` sets the text (including html elements) inside an element. Normally we use it for elements like div, span etc to insert other html elements inside it.

For your case you want to set the value of an input element. So you should use the `value` attribute.

Change `innerHTML` to `value`

```
document.getElementById('add').value = sum;
```

Comment: It worked like a charm LOL, tell you what, I know nothing about JavaScript & HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
 <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sum</TITLE>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function sum()
          {

             var num1 = document.myform.number1.value;
             var num2 = document.myform.number2.value;
             var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
             document.getElementById('add').value = sum;
          }
        </script>
      </HEAD>

      <BODY>
        <FORM NAME="myform">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number1" VALUE=""/> + 
          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number2" VALUE=""/>
          <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()"/>
          <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE=""/>
        </FORM>

      </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This should work properly.
 1. use .value instead of "innerHTML" when setting the 3rd field (input field)
 2. Close the input tags

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want the result to come up in an input box?  If not, consider a table with borders set to other than transparent and use

document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;

Comment: Yeah, display result in table is a better idea. I'll try this option.

Answer (score 0):

## With .value and INPUT tag

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Sum</TITLE>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sum()
      {

         var num1 = document.myform.number1.value;
         var num2 = document.myform.number2.value;
         var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
         document.getElementById('add').value = sum;
      }
    </script>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <FORM NAME="myform">
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number1" VALUE=""/> + 
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number2" VALUE=""/>
      <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()"/>
      <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="add" NAME="result" VALUE=""/>
    </FORM>

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

## with innerHTML and DIV

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Sum</TITLE>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sum()
      {

         var num1 = document.myform.number1.value;
         var num2 = document.myform.number2.value;
         var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
         document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = sum;
      }
    </script>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <FORM NAME="myform">
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number1" VALUE=""/> + 
      <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="number2" VALUE=""/>
      <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="=" onClick="sum()"/>
      <DIV  ID="add"></DIV>
    </FORM>

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```