# how to display input text that user has writen in a label

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display what the user has witten in an input text. I have to formslike below and on the second form I want to display on a label what the user has witten at the input part. But how can I do this...

The first form:

```
<form name="password" onsubmit="return Validate()" method="post" id="password" action="#"  >

               <label for="firstname">*First Name:</label>
               <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname1"  class="textinput"  required="required" onchange="firstnamecheck1()"><br>
```

The second form:

```
 <form name="displaylabel" method="post" id="password" action="#"  >

             <label>First Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="l1">li.innerHTML('lastname1')</label><br>
    </form>
```

How can I do this because the inner html I use above  `li.innerHTML('lastname1')` do not give result.

I use this function:

```
<script>
 function doStuff()
{myVar = document.getElementById('lastname1');
    document.getElementById('l1').value = myvar;
}
</script>
```

and this is the part of the form:

```
<div class="hideformobile" onload="doStuff();">


        <form name="displaylabel" method="post" id="password" action="#"  >

         <label>First Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="l1"></label><br>

        </form>
        </div>
```

But it still it gives no result...What can I do? Please help me

Comment: Your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11041226/1505348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an onchange function called *firstnamecheck1*. I don't know what that does, but you can either add the following functionality to that function, or add this to the inline listener:

```
<input ... onchange="firstnamecheck1(); document.getElementById('l1').innerHTML = this.value;">
```

However, I'd prefer to set the textContent or innerHTML as appropriate using something like:

```
setText(document.getElementById('l1'), this.value);
```

Requires a small helper function to set the text:

```
function setText(el, text) {
  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    el.textContent = text;
  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    el.innerText = text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the HTML content of an element you may set it's `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById('my-element').innerHTML = 'test';
```

To get/set the value of an `<input>` element, use it's `value` property.

```
document.getElementById('my-input').value = 'something';
```

Comment: On getting/setting the value of an element, the code you provided only sets the value. To get the value of a particular element the code would be `myVar = document.getElementById('my_element');` Other than that your answer is very good +1

Comment: I did it like I posted above but it still doesnt function..Can you help me , please

Comment: @VivecVelothian Well, I assumed an example for both getting and setting the property wasn't required.

Comment: @plalx That's cool, it's just that you wrote "To get/set" for the code that only sets.

Answer (score 0):

`<label>First Name:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="l1">li.innerHTML('lastname1')</label><br>`

This is not the proper way to use this javascript.  You need to run it inside a function.  If you put it in a block like

```
<script>
function doStuff()
{
    document.getElementById('l1').innerHTML = 'lastname1';
}
</script>
```

When you call `doStuff()`, that code will execute and change the innerHTML property of the list item element.  You can call this sort of function on page or body load as well.

`<body onload="doStuff();"> (more content) </body>`

Comment: I did it like I posted above but still no result..Can you help me please