# how do I show result in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how to put some results in the form'nieuwticket2'
for example: $anaam needs to be outputted in input field.

What is the best and easiest way to to this?

```js
function zoekf() {
  var zoektxt = $("input[name='zoek']").val();
  $.post("zoek.php", {
    zoekval: zoektxt
  }, function(output) {
    $("#output").html(output);
  });
}
```

```html
<form name="nieuwTicket2" action="nieuwTicket.php" method="POST">
  <button type="button" onclick="bestaandek()" id="bk">bestaandeklant</button>
  <br>
  <input name='zoek' type="text" placeholder="zoeken in Achternaam" onkeydown="zoekf();" class='hidden2' />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" name="zoekk" class='hidden2' />
</form>
<div id="output">
</div>


<?php $connectie=v erbinddatabase(); $output='' ; if (isset($_POST[ 'zoekval'])) { $searchq=$ _POST[ 'zoekval']; $searchq=p reg_replace( "#[^0-9a-z]#i", "",$searchq); $leesKlantQuery=m ysqli_query($connectie,
"SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klantAchternaam LIKE '%$searchq%';"); $count=m ysqli_num_rows($leesKlantQuery); if($count==0){ $output='geen resultaten' ; }else{ while($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($leesKlantQuery)){ $anaam=$ row[ 'klantAchternaam']; $vnaam=$row[ 'klantNaam']; $kid=$row[ 'klantId']; $output.='<div>' .$vnaam.
' '.$anaam. ' '.$kid. '</div>'; }}} echo($output); ?>
```

Comment: What happens when you run your current code? It looks like it should work.

Comment: it works, but i like it to be outputted in a inputfield. now it is just outputting in a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't be injecting `div`s into an input field:

```
$output .= '<div>'.$vnaam.' '.$anaam.' '.$kid.'</div>';
```

If you really want it in an input, concatenante:

```
$output .= $vnaam.' '.$anaam.' '.$kid.', ';
```

Then add as:

```
<input id="output" type="text" />

$.post("zoek.php", {zoekval: zoektxt}, function(output){
    $("#output").html(output);
});
```

However, if you have multiple rows, you may want to use textfield instead:

```
<textfield id="output"></textfield>

$.post("zoek.php", {zoekval: zoektxt}, function(output){
    $("#output").text(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#output').val(output);
</script>
```

And change the div with `#output` to `<input type="text" value="" id="output">`

Answer (score 0):

Another option without Jquery is,

> innerHTML sets the text (including html elements) inside an element.
>   Normally we use it for elements like div, span etc to insert other
>   html elements inside it.
>
> For your case you want to set the value of an input element. So you
>   should use the value attribute.
>
> Change innerHTML to value
>
> ```
> document.getElementById('add').value = sum;
> ```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041201/html-display-result-in-text-input-field)